# How to kill certain windows when out of focus automatically?

Tags: i3

I have i3-gaps installed and would like to kill a certain type of window instance whenever it is out of focus. Example, after launching a terminal typing in some command and then killing it once it is out of focus.

I know that the directive 
`for_window [instance="foobar"] <do something>`
can be used to instruct a certain type of command for windows of that instance. For instance dropdown windows. I am also aware of the **focused** keyword but I can't find any example on how to use it.

What I expect is something like
`for_window [instance="foobar" && __focused__] if not focused then kill`

Answer (score 0):

I'm achieving the same functionality with `xdotool`:

```
xdotool search --class xterm behave %@ blur windowclose
```

This will close an xterm window when it loses focus.
You can play with `xdotool`. It is quite flexible.